# Google Maps Plugin - Toggle KML layer

Tags: plugin-googlemaps

In the previous version of the Google Maps plugin (Smart Maps) I used something similar to this to toggle multiple KML layers:

```
    var streetLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://www.comovisionzero.org/assets/data/high-crash-network.kml', {
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: false
    })
    function toggleStreetLayer() {
        if( $("#streets").is(':checked') ) {
            streetLayer.setMap(map);
        }
        else {
            streetLayer.setMap(null);
        }
    }
```

In the new version, I'm trying to use the callback and map.kml functionality, but I'm having difficulty toggling the KML layer off:

```
  {{ map.tag({
    'callback': 'mapFilters'
    })
  }}
  <script>
  {% js %}
    function mapFilters() {
      var map = googleMaps.getMap('mapAlpha');


      function showLayer(kmlUrl) {
        map.kml(kmlUrl, {
          'preserveViewport': true
        });
      };

      function toggleStreetLayer() {
        if( $("#streets").is(':checked') ) {
          showLayer('https://www.comovisionzero.org/assets/data/high-crash-network.kml');
        }
        else {
          showLayer(null);
        }
      }

      $("input").change(function() {
          toggleStreetLayer();
      });

    }
  {% endjs %}
  </script>
```

Am I even close to being on the right track?

Comment: Easier-to-use KML functions [are coming soon](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-googlemaps/issues/24), if you don't mind waiting a few weeks.

Comment: Just added a comprehensive answer, thanks for your patience! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of **v4.0.10** of the Google Maps plugin, three new functions have been added for working with KML layers...

- [`hideKml(kmlId)`](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/dynamic-maps/universal-methods/#hidekml-kmlid) - Hide a KML layer
- [`showKml(kmlId)`](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/dynamic-maps/universal-methods/#showkml-kmlid) - Show a KML layer
- [`getKml(kmlId)`](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/dynamic-maps/javascript-methods/#getkml-kmlid) - Get the raw Google API object

These methods are explained in greater detail in the [**KML Layers**](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/guides/kml-layers/) documentation.

---

In other words, your example might look something more like this...

```
{# Create the map #}
{% set map = googleMaps.map(locations, {
    'id': 'mapAlpha',
}) %}

{# Set the KML layer URL #}
{% set url = 'https://www.comovisionzero.org/assets/data/high-crash-network.kml' %}

{# Add the KML layer #}
{% do map.kml(url, {
    'id': 'my-kml',
    'kmlLayerOptions': {
        'preserveViewport': true
    }
}) %}

{# Display the map #}
{{ map.tag() }}

{% js %}
// Toggle the street layer KML
function toggleStreetLayer() {

    // Get the existing map
    var map = googleMaps.getMap('mapAlpha');

    // Show or hide the KML layer
    if( $("#streets").is(':checked') ) {
        map.showKml('my-kml');
    }
    else {
        map.hideKml('my-kml');
    }

}
{% endjs %}
```

Worth keeping in mind that there are several other ways to approach this as well, since there are now strong parallels between JS, Twig, and PHP.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yasss! Thank you!